# tikz-cd: an extra background color not conforming to the page color

Tags: tikz-cd

Consider the following example, you can see that there is a white background behind the text label, which is not consistent to the page color. Is there any way to fix this behavior?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\pagecolor{yellow}

\begin{document}

\[
    \begin{tikzcd}
        X & X & \cdots & X \\
        Y & Y & \cdots & Y
        \arrow["T", from=1-1, to=1-2]
        \arrow["S", from=2-1, to=2-2]
        \arrow["\Phi"', from=1-1, to=2-1]
        \arrow["\Phi", from=1-2, to=2-2]
        \arrow["T", from=1-2, to=1-3]
        \arrow["S", from=2-2, to=2-3]
        \arrow["T", from=1-3, to=1-4]
        \arrow["S", from=2-3, to=2-4]
        \arrow["\Phi", from=1-4, to=2-4]
        \arrow["\displaystyle\cdots"{description}, draw=none, from=1-3, to=2-3]
    \end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fill is designed to partly obscure an arrow in a `description`. Use `background color=none` like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\pagecolor{yellow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  X & X & \cdots & X \\
  Y & Y & \cdots & Y
  \arrow["T", from=1-1, to=1-2]
  \arrow["S", from=2-1, to=2-2]
  \arrow["\Phi"', from=1-1, to=2-1]
  \arrow["\Phi", from=1-2, to=2-2]
  \arrow["T", from=1-2, to=1-3]
  \arrow["S", from=2-2, to=2-3]
  \arrow["T", from=1-3, to=1-4]
  \arrow["S", from=2-3, to=2-4]
  \arrow["\Phi", from=1-4, to=2-4]
  \arrow["\displaystyle\cdots"{description}, background color=none, draw=none, from=1-3, to=2-3]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image: Cumulative diagram on yellow background]

Comment: Thank you! Just to be curious, if my page color is called `paper`, is it possible to globally set the `background color` to be `paper`?

Comment: Yes - add to preamble: `\tikzset{/tikz/commutative diagrams/background color=paper}`

Comment: Thank you for the help, your answer and the comment above work perfectly :)